# Claims Based Security between Web client, ASP.Net MVC 4 and WCF Data Services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf-data-services, wif, claims-based-identity

Here are the following parties :

- A ASP.Net MVC 4 web application with massive use of JavaScript & ajax : `http://server1/mvcapp`
- This application do ajax calls (GET,PUT,MERGE, ...) to a WCF Data Services (in a another server - CORS enabled) for CRUD operations : `http://server2/wcfdatas`
- An ADFS 2.0 server.

I need to implement claims based security for the whole.
I see how i can do that with ASP.Net MVC Application using WIF, but it is nor clear for WCF Data Service.

For example, when it is the JavaScript code that directly call the WCF Data Service. Note that ASP.Net App and WCF Data Service are not in the same server.

Federation, delegation, WS-Trust, OAuth 2, SAML and JWT tokens, ADFS or Thinktecture IdentityServer - which can help i suppose - i don't know where to start with the problem, although i'm much documented on the subject.

Note : there is no plan for use of Azure ACS.